# What is the difference between radical ideal and the radical of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

So suppose that we have already shown that the radical of an ideal $I$, $\sqrt{I}$, is an ideal. Can we just conclude that the $\sqrt{I}$ is a radical ideal, as it is i) radical of an ideal, ii) ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "radical ideal". If it is:

> An ideal $J$ is radical if and only if there is an ideal $I$ such that $J=\sqrt I$.

Then, yes. If it is the more common version:

> An ideal $J$ is radical if and only if $\sqrt J=J$.

Then, no: you still have to prove that $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}}=\sqrt I$. The two definitions are equivalent, pretty much because of the identity $\sqrt{\sqrt{I}}=\sqrt I$.

Comment: As per the more common definition of radical ideal, if I is radical then does it mean that every element of I is of the form $a^{m}$ for $a\in$ I?

Comment: @Mathomania I don't quite know what to think of your claim. Certainly $\sqrt I=I$ does not imply that there is some $a\in I$ such that for all $x\in I$ there is some $m>0$ such that $x=a^m$. On the other hand, it is universally true that for all $x\in I$ there are some $a\in I$ and some $m>0$ such that $a^m=x$, by considering $a=x$, $m=1$.

Comment: If I is given to be a radical ideal, we have $\sqrt{I}=I$, that means every element in I should be in $\sqrt{I}$, which means every element of I should be of the form $a^{m}$. Is this claim justified?

Comment: @Mathomania You are not addressing what I said, therefore I'll repeat one last time: your sentence is not properly quantified, and therefore I can't read it.